# Not able to start weblogic portal server

Tags: exception, weblogic, startup, portal

I installed WebLogic Portal 10.3 server on linux. After creating a domain when I start weblogic I get following exception:

```
<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Error> <Security> <BEA-000000> <[Security:090759]A SQLException occurred while retrieving password information
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'WEBLOGIC' does not exist
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.DBMSSQLReadOnlyDatabaseConnectionImpl.getPreparedStatement(DBMSSQLReadOnlyDatabaseConnectionImpl.java:37)
        at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSSQLRuntimeQueryImpl.passwordStringQuery(DBMSSQLRuntimeQueryImpl.java:82)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Schema 'WEBLOGIC' does not exist
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Critical> <Security> <BEA-090402> <Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.>
<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:959)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1050)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
        at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'WEBLOGIC' does not exist
        at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.authenticateDBMS(DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:696)
        at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:271)
        at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:110)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.login(LoginModuleWrapper.java:106)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

The log file content is:

```
 ####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:56 PM IST> <Error> <Security> <localhost> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352616659> <BEA-000000> <Commit events are not broadcast because no JMS Transport is available. Remote L2 caches will be out of sync.> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:56 PM IST> <Info> <Security> <localhost> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352616660> <BEA-090075> <The SAMLCredentialMapper provider has had its LDIF information loaded from: /usr/local/Oracle/user_projects/domains/my_domain/security/SAMLCredentialMapperInit.ldift> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:56 PM IST> <Info> <Security> <localhost> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352616787> <BEA-090851> <The SAMLCredentialMapperV2 provider is initialized.> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Info> <Security> <localhost> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352617414> <BEA-090093> <No pre-WLS 8.1 Keystore providers are configured for server AdminServer for security realm myrealm.> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <localhost> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352617414> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Error> <Security> <localhost> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352617452> <BEA-000000> <[Security:090759]A SQLException occurred while retrieving password information
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'WEBLOGIC' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.DBMSSQLReadOnlyDatabaseConnectionImpl.getPreparedStatement(DBMSSQLReadOnlyDatabaseConnectionImpl.java:37)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSSQLRuntimeQueryImpl.passwordStringQuery(DBMSSQLRuntimeQueryImpl.java:82)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSSQLRuntimeQueryImpl.executeUserPassword(DBMSSQLRuntimeQueryImpl.java:72)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.authenticateDBMS(DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:672)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:271)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:110)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.login(LoginModuleWrapper.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.JAASLoginServiceImpl.login(JAASLoginServiceImpl.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.Delegator$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(Delegator.java:57)
    at $Proxy17.login(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.internal.WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl$ServiceImpl.login(WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl.java:89)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.JAASAuthenticationServiceImpl.authenticate(JAASAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.Delegator$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(Delegator.java:57)
    at $Proxy37.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.WLSJAASAuthenticationServiceWrapper.authenticate(WLSJAASAuthenticationServiceWrapper.java:40)
    at weblogic.security.service.PrincipalAuthenticator.authenticate(PrincipalAuthenticator.java:348)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:929)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1050)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused By: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Schema 'WEBLOGIC' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.DBMSSQLReadOnlyDatabaseConnectionImpl.getPreparedStatement(DBMSSQLReadOnlyDatabaseConnectionImpl.java:37)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSSQLRuntimeQueryImpl.passwordStringQuery(DBMSSQLRuntimeQueryImpl.java:82)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSSQLRuntimeQueryImpl.executeUserPassword(DBMSSQLRuntimeQueryImpl.java:72)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.authenticateDBMS(DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:672)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:271)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:110)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.login(LoginModuleWrapper.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.JAASLoginServiceImpl.login(JAASLoginServiceImpl.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.Delegator$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(Delegator.java:57)
    at $Proxy17.login(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.internal.WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl$ServiceImpl.login(WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl.java:89)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.JAASAuthenticationServiceImpl.authenticate(JAASAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.Delegator$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(Delegator.java:57)
    at $Proxy37.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.WLSJAASAuthenticationServiceWrapper.authenticate(WLSJAASAuthenticationServiceWrapper.java:40)
    at weblogic.security.service.PrincipalAuthenticator.authenticate(PrincipalAuthenticator.java:348)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:929)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1050)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Critical> <Security> <localhost> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352617465> <BEA-090402> <Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <localhost> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352617469> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:959)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1050)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused By: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'WEBLOGIC' does not exist
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.authenticateDBMS(DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:696)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.shared.DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(DBMSAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:271)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:110)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.login(LoginModuleWrapper.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.JAASLoginServiceImpl.login(JAASLoginServiceImpl.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.Delegator$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(Delegator.java:57)
    at $Proxy17.login(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.internal.WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl$ServiceImpl.login(WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl.java:89)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.JAASAuthenticationServiceImpl.authenticate(JAASAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.Delegator$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(Delegator.java:57)
    at $Proxy37.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.WLSJAASAuthenticationServiceWrapper.authenticate(WLSJAASAuthenticationServiceWrapper.java:40)
    at weblogic.security.service.PrincipalAuthenticator.authenticate(PrincipalAuthenticator.java:348)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:929)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1050)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <localhost> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352617484> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <localhost> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352617485> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <localhost> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352617488> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN> 
####<Jan 12, 2012 12:46:57 PM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <localhost> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1326352617497> <BEA-000236> <Stopping execute threads.>
```

Whats the problem and how to solve?

Comment: Error message is clear: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'WEBLOGIC' does not exist`

Comment: @Jani How can I create WEBLOGIC database?

Answer (score 1):

Dont check all the files and waste the time
simple solution :

go to WLHome/servers/Adminservers/security/boot.properties

edit the file and remove user name and password values

keep like User = 
password = 
and save it.
once it is done Restart the server next time you will find encrypted user name and password names in the boot.properties.

I'm sure this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try to kill the running process "pointbase.ini"
If doesn't work, you can try to remove the boot.properties file.